# How to setup an existing php project which used composer in a localhost with xampp?

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php

I want to run a php project on `localhost`. The project is running on cloud server and was using [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/) to install it's dependencies. Now I just downloaded the complete codebase. Since there is no composer it is not allowing to run on localhost. How can I solve this? In the localhost, I am getting error on:

> return
>   composerAutoloaderInitce131cf0428f7beac0dd4d1119bee46a::getLoader();

I tried installing composer, but resulted in an error. Maybe because of the php version, which is 7.

Comment: What is the error when you installed composer ?

Comment: The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. 
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with DNS. Can you ping `getcomposer.org` ?

Comment: I have this doubt, is that not possible to run the project in the localhost without the composer?

Comment: It's depend on how you use composer, but if some dependencies you need are not installed this will not work. 

Furthermore, if you use the autoload from `composer` then you won't have it and it will not work.